# Restoring image files from earlier commit

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I need to revert binary images to an earlier commit. This may seem like a simple question but how do I revert back to an earlier image? It's almost 30 commits earlier if that matters.

Also, and this is probably where the confusion comes in, there are three branches I see:

- origin

  - ApacheBranch
  - HEAD
  - master

Not sure which one to choose.

Comment: "Not sure which one to choose." How do you expect us to know? You haven't given nearly enough information for that. It shouldn't matter, though...

Comment: Yeah, I just want the most recent branch. There is origin, head and master and then I created ApacheBranch I would rather use the most recent one besides that one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to select the image in SourceTree and then select Log and then choose the version I wanted. If I just chose Reset to commit it would return the last committed image.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you know the hash of the commit from which you want to retrieve the files.

Try this:

```
git checkout <hash> -- path/to/file
```

You should end up with the file modified as it was at `<hash>`, staged for commit. You can repeat this command for other files; the changes from each will be added to the staging area.

Once you're happy with the changes, simply `git commit` and use a commit message along the lines of

```
Revert path/to/file to version from <hash>
```